# How to get users of a group in a group AD PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to get all Members of a group `testgroup1`, but inside this group are other groups `testgroup2`, `testgroup3`.

The output of `Get-ADGroupMember "testgroup1"` is a list of members inside `testgroup1` but it lists all the other groups inside like Members.

How can I get all members of the `testgroup1` **and** all the members of the groups that are inside it?

Comment: What is the command which you are using?

Comment: It's from the ActiveDirectory default module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation for [Get-ADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember#optional-parameters) you'll find a parameter called `Recursive`

This will check the memberships of any child groups (groups that are in your group), and display the members of those groups as well as the direct members of your group.

Simply update you command like this:

```
Get-ADGroupMember "testgroup1" -Recursive
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the switch parameter Recursive

Example:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "yourgroup" -Recursive
```

Take a look at the documentation of the cmdlt on technet https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh852290(v=wps.630).aspx